# StopPropagation in HTML with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am having a problem with stopPropagation, I don't know how to write in html and typescript for angular.
It opens the dialog but at the same time makes a propagation.

Here is my code in `HTML`:

```
<label for="tab-two">PROJECTS
    <a class="plus" (click)="opentestdialog()">+</a>
</label>
```

And here is my code in `TypeScript`:

```
opentestdialog() {
    this.dialog.open(TestdialogComponent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

thank's for your time but I have found the problem. 
I just wrote.

```
<a class="plus" (click)="opentestdialog(); false">+</a>
```

Thank you so much, maybe it will be helpfull for someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation();opentestdialog()"
```

or

```
(click)="opentestdialog($event)"
```

```
opentestdialog(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  this.dialog.open(TestdialogComponent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but it is not working,  I have the same issue again.

Comment: Then it's probably not related to even propagation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML:

```
<a class="plus" ng-click="opentestdialog($event)">+</a>
```

This is the typescript file:

```js
public opentestdialog(event: angular.IAngularEvent) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.dialog.open(TestdialogComponent);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have a issue in TS like: Cannot find namespace 'angular'

Comment: try to remove the type "angular.IAngularEvent" first just to see if you get the expected behavior:
public opentestdialog(event) {..}

Answer (score 0):

you can just

```
<a class="plus" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">+</a>
```